# How can I clone a 120GB ssd to a 80GB one?

Tags: cloning

Would someone know how to do this? I have cloned equal sized harddrives before with dd but I don't know how to clone a bigger one to a smaller one. The 120GB ssd has less than 50Gb worth of data fyi. How can I do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `resize2fs` (see `man resize2fs`) to shrink your existing partition from 120GB to 80GB (since you have only 50GB of data). Then, use your standard 80GB to 80GB clone process.

Comment: @answerSeeker, This works well when there is an MSDOS partition table. But if there is a GUID partition table, GPT, there is a backup of the partition table at the tail end of the drive, and it can be restored afterwards with `gdisks`. The script `gpt-fix` according to the following link might do it 'semi-automatically', https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#gpt-fix